# Implement `flatten` for `Cons`

Tags: haskell

Given the following definition of `Cons`:

```
data Cons a = Cons a (Cons a) 
             | Empty 
             deriving Show
```

I implemented a `flatten` function.

It's mean to work exactly like `concat :: [[a]] -> [a]`, but for `Cons`.

```
flatten :: Cons (Cons a) -> Cons a
flatten Empty                = Empty
flatten (Cons (Empty) ys)    = flatten ys
flatten (Cons (Cons x xs) ys) = Cons x (flatten (Cons xs ys))
```

Test data:

```
test1 :: Cons (Cons Int)
test1 = Cons (Cons 5 Empty) Empty

test2 :: Cons (Cons Int)
test2 = Cons (Cons 5 (Cons 10 Empty)) Empty

test3 :: Cons (Cons Int)
test3 = Cons (Cons 5 (Cons 10 (Cons 20 Empty))) test2
```

Some tests:

```
ghci> flatten test1
Cons 5 Empty

ghci> flatten test2
Cons 5 (Cons 10 Empty)

ghci> flatten test3
Cons 5 (Cons 10 (Cons 20 (Cons 5 (Cons 10 Empty))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, unless you wanted to add instances to allow for folding and so, or conversions to `Data.List` I'd say that's perfect as it is.